# About soap based web service

Tags: java, soap

I am generating SOAP based web services and it's not working for java 6 and netbeans 7 but working fine with java8 and netbeans 8.

Is there specific reason for that?

```
SEVERE: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.xml.ws.WebFault.messageName()Ljava/lang/String;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]I too faced a similar problem while working on SOAP web services with JAVA 1.6 and netbeans 8.
I had it fixed by creating the "endorsed" directory in my CATALINA_HOME and placing my required jar (ie) "webservices-api.jar" in the "endorsed" directory.

-The real problem is that the JDK comes with its specific set of JARs as well, and picks up those JARS by default and ignores the project specific included JARs. To override the JDK JARs, tomcat provides the endorsed feature which helps to override the JARs available in the JDK.

The default location of the "endorsed" directory is CATALINA_HOME. 
In case, you want to change yo[ur endorsed directory path, you would require to change the path of the endorsed directory in your catalina.bat file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvr0Y.png)